# Color area inside curved lines in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I drew this picture
[image]
with the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (mth) [align=center] at (0,0) {parameter space of\\[2ex]{\Large M-Theory}};
    \node (so32) [align=center] at (-5,-1) {heterotic\\$SO(32)$};
    \node (e8e8) [align=center] at (-3,4) {heterotic\\$E(8) \times E(8)$};
    \node (tiia) [align=center] at (4,3) {Type II A};
    \node (tiib) [align=center] at (5,-2) {Type II B};
    \node (ti) [align=center] at (0,-5) {Type I};

    \draw[bend left,<->]  (so32) to node [below right,align=center] {compac-\\tification} (e8e8);
    \draw[bend left,<->]  (e8e8) to node [below left] {M-theory} (tiia);
    \draw[bend left,<->]  (tiia) to node [below left] {T-duality} (tiib);
    \draw[bend left,<->]  (tiib) to node [above left,align=center] {orientifold\\action $\Omega$} (ti);
    \draw[bend left,<->]  (ti) to node [above right] {S-duality} (so32);

    \draw[bend right,very thick]  (so32.east) to (e8e8.south);
    \draw[bend right,very thick]  (e8e8.south) to (tiia.south);
    \draw[bend right,very thick]  (tiia.south) to (tiib.west);
    \draw[bend right,very thick]  (tiib.west) to (ti.north);
    \draw[bend right,very thick]  (ti.north) to (so32.east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to color the area closed off by the thick black lines, i.e. the `parameter space`, a light gray. Does anyone know of an easy way to do this? Also, how can I add curved gray lines to the five corners as in this image?

[image]

Comment: you can fill an area if you draw it as a single path, not as separate draw commands

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could at multiple points to a `\draw` command. I'm just learning `tikz`. That takes care of the first part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the coloring of the background, you can draw it all as one path, and fill that. For the curved gray lines, you can use clipping and circles as in the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\node (mth)  [align=center] at (0,0)   {parameter space of\\[2ex]{\Large M-Theory}};
\node (so32) [align=center] at (-5,-1) {heterotic\\$SO(32)$};
\node (e8e8) [align=center] at (-3,4)  {heterotic\\$E(8) \times E(8)$};
\node (tiia) [align=center] at (4,3)   {Type II A};
\node (tiib) [align=center] at (5,-2)  {Type II B};
\node (ti)   [align=center] at (0,-5)  {Type I};

\draw[bend left,<->]  (so32) to node [below right,align=center] {compac-\\tification} (e8e8);
\draw[bend left,<->]  (e8e8) to node [below left] {M-theory} (tiia);
\draw[bend left,<->]  (tiia) to node [below left] {T-duality} (tiib);
\draw[bend left,<->]  (tiib) to node [above left,align=center] {orientifold\\action $\Omega$} (ti);
\draw[bend left,<->]  (ti)   to node [above right] {S-duality} (so32);

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \draw[bend right,very thick, fill=lightgray]
    (so32.east)
      to (e8e8.south)
      to (tiia.south)
      to (tiib.west)
      to (ti.north)
      to (so32.east);

  \begin{scope}
    \clip[bend right]
      (so32.east)
        to (e8e8.south)
        to (tiia.south)
        to (tiib.west)
        to (ti.north)
        to (so32.east);
    \foreach \c in {so32.east,e8e8.south,tiia.south,tiib.west,ti.north,so32.east}{%
      \foreach \r in {1,...,4}{%
        \draw[darkgray] (\c) circle (\r*0.25cm);
      }
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which results in

[image: Output]

You can of course customize the colors of both the fill and the curves to your liking.

Comment: That's perfect and much simpler than I thought it would be. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the first part just construct the inner path as a single `\draw` command without breaking the path:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (so32) [align=center] at (-5,-1) {heterotic\\$SO(32)$};
    \node (e8e8) [align=center] at (-3,4) {heterotic\\$E(8) \times E(8)$};
    \node (tiia) [align=center] at (4,3) {Type II A};
    \node (tiib) [align=center] at (5,-2) {Type II B};
    \node (ti) [align=center] at (0,-5) {Type I};

    \draw[bend left,<->]  (so32) to node [below right,align=center] {compac-\\tification} (e8e8);
    \draw[bend left,<->]  (e8e8) to node [below left] {M-theory} (tiia);
    \draw[bend left,<->]  (tiia) to node [below left] {T-duality} (tiib);
    \draw[bend left,<->]  (tiib) to node [above left,align=center] {orientifold\\action $\Omega$} (ti);
    \draw[bend left,<->]  (ti) to node [above right] {S-duality} (so32);

    \draw[bend right,very thick,fill=black!20]
      (so32.east) to (e8e8.south)
       to (tiia.south)
       to (tiib.west)
       to (ti.north)
       to (so32.east)
      ;
    \node (mth) [align=center] at (0,0) {parameter space of\\[2ex]{\Large M-Theory}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I had to move the `mth` node below the filled area so it shows up on top of it.
If you need to create it before that but still have it on the foreground you can use

```
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
```

and then draw the filled path in the background:

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \draw[bend right,very thick,fill=black!20]
      (so32.east) to (e8e8.south)
       to (tiia.south)
       to (tiib.west)
       to (ti.north)
       to (so32.east)
      ;
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

---

For the second question, you may find the `angles` library useful, it is documented in the manual of the last version of PGF at section 39.